# Screen doesn't lock automatically

Tags: 12.04, screen, lock, automatic

I have Ubuntu 12.04. No matter what I adjust the screen to. The screen does not lock automatically after any number of minutes. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Can you add to your question what methods you tried to lock the screen?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. The screen only automatically locks, when it is set to lock as soon as the display turns off. Due to a bug with ATI and Compiz I had to disable the latter. Now my system only locks when done so manually. Changing the timer under "Brightness and Lock" preferences has no effect.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.